# VS Code terminal unable to privide UTF-8 input

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, input, terminal, utf-8

I'm hopeful that this question is a duplicate, but I have searched a *lot* at this point, and I've not come across anything helpful, so I am dubious.

The following simple Java code works perfectly in Eclipse, which has its own home-built terminal, and on any *nix system (such as Macs):<sup>(1)</sup>

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
    System.out.println("File encoding is " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

    Scanner console = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    PrintStream sysout = new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    sysout.println("\nTests:");
    sysout.println("Can we print lambda using unicode? Let's see: \u03BB");
    
    sysout.print("Copy and paste the lambda above here: ");
    String line = console.nextLine();

    sysout.println("\nThe input consisted of " + line.length() + " character(s).");
    sysout.println("The input was: " + line);

    if (line.equals("λ")) {
        sysout.println("lambda (λ) was detected with .equals!");
    } else {
        sysout.println("lambda (λ) was not detected with .equals.");
    }

    printHexOfString("Hex of λ", "λ");
    printHexOfString("Hex of input", line);
}



private static void printHexOfString(String title, String str) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

    for (char c : charArray) {
        String charToHex = Integer.toHexString(c);
        stringBuilder.append(charToHex);
    }

    System.out.println(title+ ": "+stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

## Eclipse Joy

When I type a lambda, I receive the expected output:

```
File encoding is UTF-8

Tests:
Can we print lambda using unicode? Let's see: λ
Copy and paste the lambda above here: λ

The input consisted of 1 character(s).
The input was: λ
lambda (λ) was detected with .equals!
Hex of λ: 3bb
Hex of input: 3bb
```

Hooray!

## VS Code Troubles

However, all is not so nice in VS Code, which uses Windows Powershell.  I ran `chcp 65001` in the terminal at the bottom of VS Code before anything else.  (Note: prior to my command, `chcp` by itself reports `Active code page: 437`, and after I type my command, I get the expected `Active code page: 65001`)

There, running the same code, and inputting the same lambda, I get:

```
File encoding is UTF-8

Tests:
Can we print lambda using unicode? Let's see: λ
Copy and paste the lambda above here: λ

The input consisted of 1 character(s).
The input was:
lambda (Î») was not detected with .equals.
Hex of Î»: cebb
Hex of input: 0
```

## What I need

I'm not sure where to go from here.  I need the lambda symbol to be read, processed, and written to the console consistently.  I don't need the rest of UTF-8, I only need the one symbol, so any hacky solution that gains me a lambda will be well received.

Bonus points if the solution doesn't break everything in Eclipse and in Unix (where the original code already works fine).

<sup>(1) - As an aside, I tried all 6 character encodings in `StandardCharsets` for my `PrintStream` and `InputStreamReader`, and while the numbers changed, the lambda was never detected (so it never output "`String is λ`"), and the last line printed was never a lambda.)</sup>

Comment: There are two factors of importance: encoding and font support. The lambda character is quite exotic. Are you sure your font supports it?

Comment: Also, from the POV of the first, it might be useful if you reopened and did *just* `chcp` and told us what it prints

Comment: @g00se The character renders in the font, because I can paste it as my input just fine.  `chcp` returns `Active code page: 437`, and after I type my command, I get `Active code page: 65001`.

Comment: @g00se It's not *so* exotic!  It's in the Greek alphabet, and it's probably in the top ten Greek letters frequently used in math (which is why I need it, for a λ calculus lab assignment that I have created.)

Comment: Well let's put it this way: it only appears in *one* of the ISO charsets and that's the one with Greek language support. You can use [this](http://technojeeves.com/tech/Lambda.java) for testing. Run that. Then run it again after `chcp 869`

Comment: @g00se I got a question mark both times, but a lambda after `chcp 65001`.  What have I just tested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244665/discussion-between-g00se-and-ben-i).

Comment: @Ben I. I run the code on chcp 869 and deleted the limitation that line one and two :StandardCharsets.UTF_8. I can get λ in the output of terminal. However, it still cannot pass judgment. So I didn't get "String is λ". I think this involves the character set of code and terminal, the method .equals() cannot work.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Yeah, if you look at my recent edit, it appears that Java is receiving a null byte in place of the lambda.  However, it works in other environments.  Do you imagine that there would be a way to get around this, or would this be some sort of strict limit to powershell?

Comment: @Ben I. After many attempts, I failed. I tried to submit GitHub, hoping to get some information to solve the problem. In fact, all this is because vscode itself uses the CMD shell of windows, and eclipse has its own terminal.

Comment: I tried all this on WIndows. Long story short: you'll be fine with cmd.exe if you use the Unicode escape code for lambda in your source (I'd define it as a constant, then you can just use `LAMBDA`) and ensure you chcp 65001. You should be able to copy a lambda character into the terminal if you can't type it. You can probably do the Alt-Numpad trick too but I didn't try that. I can put up the longer story when you've confirmed [or refuted ;)] what I just stated.

Comment: @g00se Even the comparison works?  I'm surprised to hear that it works in cmd but not in Powershell.

Comment: You mean the bit starting *if (line.equals("λ")) {*? If so, I had trouble with that. afaicr it even crashed but I sort of ignored that as being 'anti-Ockham's Razor'. I can look at that as a separate thing later. For now, can you call `line.trim()` and also try `line.contains(LAMBDA)` to see what happens

Comment: @g00se Yeah, it needs to be able to compare, because my students' parsers need the symbol as a signal that they are seeing a lambda function rather than a lambda application.

Comment: I'll check it out again later. I must admit that there are mentions about of `chcp 65001` being hacky so there could be inconsistencies. You might know this but fyi `0xce0xbb` is the UTF-8 encoding of the lambda character as raw bytes